Rust crate quickjs fails execution of simple script with "SyntaxError: stack overflow"
In my Rust based project, I am using quick-js library for running custom javascript code.  Everything is working fine locally (including cargo test which shows all 4 testcases passed).  However, when I push the code to github and run the workflow, it fails all the tests with an exception SyntaxError: stack overflow.
My code is very simple and not performing any complex javascript operations for testing. The source file 'test_context.js' has a struct which stores quickjs runtime context.
pub struct TestCtx {
    pub client: reqwest::blocking::Client,
    pub jwt_token: Option<String>,
    pub runtime: quick_js::Context,

    // More fields as necessary
    exec_duration: std::time::Duration,
}

The struct is properly initialized in the new method.  In this, a JS runtime is created, a global object called 'SAT' is created and then a function SAT.test is added to the SAT object.
impl TestCtx {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let runtime = Context::new().unwrap();
        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

        // Initialize SAT as an empty object
        runtime.eval("var SAT = {}").unwrap();

        // define the 'SAT.test' function
        runtime
            .eval(
                r#"
                SAT.test = function (name, fn) {
                    SAT.testName = name;
                    let result = false;
                    try {
                        result = fn();
                        if (typeof result !== 'boolean') {
                            result = false;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        // Handle error
                       result = false;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            "#,
            )
            .unwrap();

        TestCtx {
            client,
            jwt_token: None,
            runtime,
            exec_duration: std::time::Duration::new(0, 0),
        }
    }

The below is a sample test code from the same file.  The javascript code is
#[test]
    fn test_sat_test_for_true() {
        // Create a new TestCtx instance
        let tctx = TestCtx::new();

        // Create a mock function that returns true
        let mock_fn = "function() { return true; }";

        // Call SAT.test with the mock function
        let result = tctx
            .runtime
            .eval(&format!("SAT.test('test', {})", mock_fn))
            .unwrap();

        // Check if the return value is true
        let expected = quick_js::JsValue::Bool(true);
        assert_eq!(result, expected);
    }


I have 3 more tests of similar nature.  Everything is working just perfect on my local PC (tested on WSL Ubuntu 22) and also on native Ubuntu 22.  However, it fails while building workflow on the Github server.  Here is the part of the output.

failures:
---- test_context::tests::test_new stdout ---- thread 'test_context::tests::test_new' panicked at
src/test_context.rs:173:58: called Result::unwrap() on an Err
value: Exception(String("SyntaxError: stack overflow")) note: run with
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
---- test_context::tests::test_sat_test_error stdout ---- thread 'test_context::tests::test_sat_test_error' panicked at
src/test_context.rs:228:14: called Result::unwrap() on an Err
value: Exception(String("SyntaxError: stack overflow"))
---- test_context::tests::test_sat_test_non_boolean stdout ---- error: test failed, to rerun pass --lib thread
'test_context::tests::test_sat_test_non_boolean' panicked at
src/test_context.rs:209:14: called Result::unwrap() on an Err
value: Exception(String("SyntaxError: stack overflow"))
---- test_context::tests::test_sat_test_for_true stdout ---- thread 'test_context::tests::test_sat_test_for_true' panicked at
src/test_context.rs:190:14: called Result::unwrap() on an Err
value: Exception(String("SyntaxError: stack overflow"))

Finally, here is the output on my WSL, which works just fine.

running 4 tests test test_context::tests::test_new ... ok test
test_context::tests::test_sat_test_error ... ok test
test_context::tests::test_sat_test_non_boolean ... ok test
test_context::tests::test_sat_test_for_true ... ok
test result: ok. 4 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered
out; finished in 0.09s

Thanks in advance for telling me where to look for the issue and how to fix it.

On the Github also, the job is configured to run on Ubuntu, but latest.
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

